Containerization has revolutionized other modes, why not aviation?
It is obvious the "container" concept (that has revolutionized other modes) as a separate drive train (wings/engines/cockpit etc) and sausage tube filled with passengers is technically feasible. Considering the considerable time wasted embarking/disembarking this has to be an economically sound transition. Why hasn't this concept been applied?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_load_device

That idea even has been patented: See here. More answers to this question can be found here.

The thing you're missing is people load themselves, so they load in parallel with one flight attendant supervising 10s of people simultaneously finding their seat. Cardboard boxes and baggage require at least one human to actively pick up and load.

Well, and it's even more than that, the human loading process is happening in parallel with many other processes (cargo & food loading, fueling, inspections, crew prep, etc.) so even though boarding is relatively slow, it's not really the limiting factor to how fast the plane can turn around.

Containerization has been adopted in aviation too and it has been done in the same way as in any other segment of transport industry: for cargo, in the form of Unit Load Decives (ULD).
Your question seems to imply that containerization was common when it comes to passengers. It is not. There are no applications in any mode of transportation (land, sea, air) where people would first embark in a cabin which was then attached to a separate system providing the propulsion.
This would, for aviation at least, add considerable amounts of complexity and possible points of failure. Considering the typical aircraft layout,  the cockpit, wings and tail would need a loadbearing "exoskeleton" adding huge amounts of weight. Taking the cabin to the airframe and attaching it to it would need specialized equipment that would need to be available at both ends of the journey.
Also, I cannot see how this would actually save time. People would still have to embark the cabin, and the cargo would need to be onloaded too. The cabin would then have to be transported to the airframe, and be attached to it.

An historical precedent would be the Train ferry, where the passenger carriages are loaded onto a ship without the passengers having to disembark.  However, I agree that this isn't a reasonable model for aviation, where the "train" would just carry passengers from the terminal to the apron.

Train ferry for sure is a close match, I may need to rephrase my answer. However weight considerations would require a specifically made human containers, not quite the same as train ferry.

The passenger part doesn’t have to be structural. Consider the seats on pallets on the QC variants of the 727/737. Just put people on them first.

I don't have the rep to do it myself and not much else to change, so somebody please change Decives to Devices.

"imply that containerization was common when it comes to passengers. It is not."   The passenger railway carriage dating way back is containerization although not intermodal - the transition to HiRail is intermodal although that seems to be more focused on heavy loads to reduce carbon footprint.  Innovation requires creativity not a "can't do attitude".  My question is not "can it be done?" - that is a given - its "why isn't it the norm?

@AnthonyLampard good point on railways you are absolutely correct on that. However, one must remember that innovation is something new and useful. You can bet your behind aviation has the most brilliant minds making design decisions such as this. Containerization simply is not feasible in aviation. Your question "why isn't it the norm" carries the presupposition it was feasible.

@user71659 to be brutally honest seats on pallets seem like a very, very bad idea. Transferring and securing the pallets, extra weight of pallet structure etc. etc...

@Jpe61 The thing is seats on pallets are much cheaper than buying, operating and maintaining 2 completely separate planes, hence the 727 and 737QC, available up to the NGs. It's also done on military aircraft, like the C-17 and C-130, from ordinary seats to full VIP suites.

@user71659 you can't really compare military and civillian solutions  Or well, you can, but it makes no sense. Btw: the F-35 is a containerized human air transport platform. The specialty of this platform is, that the pallet size is one human, and the pallet can be ejected from the acft mid flight, expediting the load delivery.

Containerizing humans has never been done, attempting, or more than fancifully proposed.
Intermodal ISO containers were designed for weight-insensitive modes of transport, such as ships, trucks and trains. They're very durable, built to stand up to the elements, break-ins, and stack ten-high. That also makes them heavy.
You'll notice that most container carriers carry them on the outside: trucks, trains, and partially ships; they're also stored outdoors, exposed to the elements. They have to be tough for that. Airplanes carry cargo on the inside, due to aerodynamics, and don't need it encased in such protection. They aren't as large as ships either.
The only aircraft intended to primarily carry ISO containers was Boeing Pelican, a 3,000-ton GEV/ekranoplan. Even that was mostly for military purposes, as the military favors containers (often as small as 1/3 TEU) for speed and flexibility over fuel economy.
